# More Mod_rewrite problems

Tags: mod-rewrite

Ok, have a client that has existing links coming in from searchmarketing.  I am in process of migrating the program from Cold Fusion to PHP.

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^cat_ap~([^~]+)~(.*)\.htm$ /urban/cat_ap.php?$1=$2 [R]
```

Currently I have a URL structure:

```
http://www.test.com/urban/cat_ap~nid~5964.htm
```

which the above rewrite rule changes to

```
http://www.test.com/urban/cat_ap.php?nid=5964
```

Now I want to be able to get the variables out of the query string but maintain the url in the browser to the original http://www.test.com/urban/cat_ap~nid~5964.htm but still have it go to the PHP page.

So that when someone goes to `http://www.test.com/urban/cat_ap~nid~5964.htm`  it actually goes to `http://www.test.com/urban/cat_ap.php?nid=5964` but still shows `http://www.test.com/urban/cat_ap~nid~5964.htm`.

Any ideas on how to do this?

Thanks

Mike

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are already doing this on this line (but change the R flag to L):

```
RewriteRule ^/urban/cat_ap~([^~]+)~(.*).htm$ /urban/cat_ap.php?$1=$2 [L]
```

The URL that the user hits will still show as the .htm version while the server processes it as the .php

Comment: The R flag redirects the user to the new URL.  Additionally, I think $1 in the original RewriteRule would be the name of the variable name, whereas your revised RewriteRule sets this to be a value.  Mike specifies the example of nid=5964

Answer (score 0):

The [`R` flag](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewriteflags) explicitly induces an external redirect. So just remove the `R` flag.

Answer (score 0):

I think you'll need to set up reverse proxying to achieve the desired behaviour, and use the P flag with your rewrite rules.  I've used a site with this sort of configuration before, so can say that it works, but I'm afraid I've never configured it myself :-(

A good first step at least would be to install mod_proxy and get it loaded and running.  The [mod_rewrite cookbook page on the P flag](http://rewrite.drbacchus.com/rewritewiki/Flags_2fP) has a small amount of detail on proxying RewriteRules, and links through to the ProxyPassReverse directive documentation at apache.org.